# OllyDBG: WS32_32.send is not in a function?

Tags: send, ollydbg

What does it mean? Did I do something wrong? I'm attached to a game in it's "adobe air" module.
I'm going by his tutorial, by the way: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WeBonE9h6B4&ebc=ANyPxKpZpghX5xhno2fMAOlSyLCsaMH1bUTutdb4sYJmx_GMmLSm46qVEmMm6gWSjNGWYb9Xu7Jh

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nuq0p.png

Answer (score 1):

If you want to set breakpoint on all ws32_send calls, follow this steps:

1. Load your target into OllyDbg
2. Use keyboard shortcut CTRL+G
3. Enter ws2_32.send
4. Choose function and press Follow expression
5. Press F2 to set breakpoint
6. Run your target (F9)